# SQLite Database error "("

Tags: sql, sqlite

This query gives the following error in SQLite Database

```
(select course_id
from section
where semester = 'Spring' and year = 2010)
intersect
(select course_id
from section
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009)
```

ERROR : near "(": syntax error:

However, it works fine when I remove the brackets.

```
select course_id
from section
where semester = 'Spring' and year = 2010
intersect
select course_id
from section
where semester = 'Fall' and year = 2009
```

Any idea?

Comment: Remove the parentheses.  I know SQLite doesn't like them for `union`/`union all` either.

Comment: They are useless anyway, so why would you want them?

Comment: Or switch to ms-access. It loves parenteses.... :-)

Comment: In case your query is part of something bigger and you need the parentheses, you can also add a `select * from (...)`.

Comment: You are looking for ideas how to make it work, aren't you? Or more for ideas on why or in which way exactly this fails?